# Google Apps Script: HTML Service from Library Can't Execute Any Functions (potential browser security issue?)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to develop a library which generates an HTML sidebar and allows the user to click buttons to call certain library functions. This would be linked to a number of spreadsheets, so the end users can open the HTML sidebar and execute various functions defined in the library. I know that to call a library function from an HTML service, you must first execute a function defined in the same project, which then calls the external library. However, the HTML service can only call functions when I'm running it in the parent library environment. When I open the HTML sidebar in another spreadsheet and click the button, it isn't able to execute any function.

## Library Project

Deployed and referenced here as "testLibrary"

**Library.gs**

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

**Page.html** (in the library project)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
Sample sidebar
<input type="button" value="Execute client function" onclick='someClientFunction()' />
<script>
  function someClientFunction(){
      google.script.run.clientFunction1();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

## Separate Spreadsheet w/ Script

**Spreadsheet Script** - linked to the library

```
// This function successfully opens the HTML sidebar
function showSidebar(){
  testLibrary.showSidebar();
}

// This function works when called on its own. I want to call this from the  library's HTML sidebar.
function clientFunction1(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("Client function executed");
}
```

[image: Image of what the inspector shows when I click the button]

Comment: It seems that this situation has already been reported at issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151466013 Also, you can see the workaround at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61173465/7108653). But in that case, it seems that it is required to also authorize the scopes in the library side. When it is not done, the error of `Uncaught` occurs. Please be careful this. When you want to run `clientFunction1`, please put it to the library side and disable V8 runtime at the client side and test it again. But I thought that this might be not the direction you expect.

Comment: Thanks, for the link, I appreciate it! I'll try this workaround. Before I do, could you tell me more about the "Please be careful with this"? Is this a security issue? Or is it more about running into compatibility problems between the old and new engines? I'm an okay scripter but new to security related stuff.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Is this a security issue?`, I think that it might be no. About `is it more about running into compatibility problems between the old and new engines?`, I think that it might be yes. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that when V8 runtime is enabled, `google.script.run` cannot directly run the function at the client side. But this might be resolve in the future update. So how about adding the start at the issue tracker?

Comment: Good news! The workaround on the thread you linked worked great - and I didn't have to disable v8! I still don't entirely understand it. I'll edit this shortly to reflect the answer.