# How to handle callback from HTML file in a Google script library

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Here's my scenario:
I have a Google script (SCRIPT) that imports another as a library (LIB_A).  LIB_A contains several HTML files that have callbacks that reside in LIB_A.  LIB_A works fine stand-alone, but I want to be able to use it in multiple Google Sheets without having a code maintenance nightmare.

What works:
I am able to launch the HTML dialog that resides in LIB_A file from SCRIPT

What doesn't work:
the callback in the HTML file is not firing (it does when LIB_A runs standalone).

Here is the HTML file that resides in LIB_A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="data">
    <label id="chooseMonth">Choose any month:</label>
    <select id="month"></select>

    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var options = "";

        for(var i=0; i<months.length; i++) {
          options += "<option>"+ months[i] + "</option>";
        }
      
        document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = options;
        const d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex =d.getMonth();
      }
    </script>
    <br /><center><input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn1" /><center>
  </div>
  <div id="resp" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Response</h1>
    <p>Month has been addded.</p>
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(validate);
      });
      function setResponse(a)
      {
        if(a)
        {
          $('#data').css('display','none');
          $('#resp').css('display','block');
        }
      }

      function validate()
      {
        document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('month').value || '';
        var a = [txt1];
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setResponse).getReportDataCallback(a);
        google.script.host.close();
        return true;
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {
          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the function that works stand-alone in the LIB_A file:

```
/*
 Called from the HTML dialog
 */
function getReportDataCallback(a) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert message");
  a = a || [];
  var monthName = a[0]
  if (monthName == YEAR_SHEET_NAME) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Creating yearly report")
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Updating \"" + monthName + "\" monthly report")
  }
  if (deleteMonth(monthName)) {
    var ss
    if (monthName == YEAR_SHEET_NAME) {
      ss = createMonthSheet("Year")
    } else {
      ss = createMonthSheet(monthName)
    } 
    if (ss != null) {
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1)
      fillTenantDataForReport(monthName)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Finished updating \"" + monthName + "\" report")
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried duplicating the getReportDataCallback() function in SCRIPT, but that is never called either.  I really don't want to duplicate the HTML files in all of the scripts that call LIB_A if I can avoid it.

My question:  How can I get this callback from the HTML to fire?  At this point, I don't care where it calls a function (I would prefer it to be in LIB_A, but SCRIPT would be fine as well)

Comment: Its interesting to note that if I rename getReportDataCallback() in SCRIPT and I click the submit button, the HTML dialog crashes (at least it closes when the function matches the HTML).  I have tried changing the function signature (and call) to only have one parameter, but I get the same results.

Comment: I can replicate what you're experiencing & I can see that when the button is clicked on the HTML dialog, an error "Uncaught TypeError: ...(...).getReportDataCallback is not a function" shows on my browser console log. But I'm no longer able to decipher this error further. By the looks of it, this could possibly be an issue (see this related post at https://stackoverflow.com/q/61173465 & also this related bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151466013 ). Better yet, you could also file a new bug report that's specific to your setup at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new

Comment: I have created the bug report as suggested.  How did you see the error?  I have not been able to get any feedback at all from callbacks.  Nevermind - I found it in the javascript console

Comment: According to this bug report, it cannot be done?!?!?! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197664258